# Export to OpenLayers plugin doesn't work with raster and WMS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to export a QGIS_2.4 project to OpenLayers using the "Export to OpenLayers" plugin. I cannot export a raster layer. I am not getting any error message, but the raster layer doesn't appear in the preview window.

I have followed all rules in the plugin web page. [Export to OpenLayers](https://github.com/volaya/qgis-ol3/blob/master/doc/usage.rst)

*Raster layers: They will be exported to JPEG files and reprojected into the default projection of the OL3 map to create (as EPSG:3857). The symbology is not used, so the layer must be a rendered image already. You can use the QGIS Save as rendered image functionality to get such an image from your data and symbology.*

Any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Can you add what kind of raster source you use? And what about the WMS you included in the title? WMS service must be in EPSG:3857 (from the docs).

Comment: I used a georeferenced rendered tif. The wms is that one http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx?

Comment: I used a georeferenced 3 band rendered tif.The wms is that one http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx? . When the wms added to the project naothing apears in the preview window. To be honest i don't know the role of EPSG:3857. How the raster and wms must be to get it out?

Comment: The WMS service only offers EPSG:4326 and WPSG:2100, so no chance. The plugin (or Openlayers3) will not reproject the WMS service. What CRS has the raster?

Comment: Raster is also EPSG=2100.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the plugin is currently rather experimental.

Loading the start page directly fails for me in Firefox because of security issues when loading `file:///` adresses. If I place the files in a folder that I can access with my local Apache server as `http://localhost`, I get the start page working.

It is then able to display OSM background and vector layers.

Raster layers should be converted to jpg by the plugin, but I don't find that jpg in the folder it should be. I reprojected the raster layer using QGIS to EPSG:3857, converted it myself to jpg using GIMP and put it in the layers subfolder. It then appears in the browser as expected.

If I have a WMS service in my QGIS project that can serve EPSG:3857, the plugin creates an OL file that hangs up before displaying anything because of missing quotation marks around the url. This can be fixed manually in `layers/layers.js`:

```
var lyr_DLM = new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                          url: "http://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dlm50",
                          params: {"LAYERS": "nw_dlm50", "TILED": "true"},
                        })),
                        title: "DLM50"
                      });
```

The quotation marks after the url: were missing, everything else was written by the plugin. This may not work if the WMS server does not support EPSG:3857, or tiled WMS.

Comment: Yes i noticed that no jpeg file is created. How you convert the file to jpg so as it is still georeferenced?

Comment: The jpg needs no georeferencing. That information is written into the layers.js file. But you have to use Raster->Translate from EPSG:2100 to EPSG:3857 and a new name before starting the plugin.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!! Raster works fine. Can you please tell me the syntax for the wms?  Where to put the quotation marks in the layers.js?

Comment: See my extended answer. But I doubt that the WMS you mentioned supports EPSG:3857.

Comment: I did it but nothing hapened. WMS works fine in QGIS using EPSG:3857.  Here is the code for openlayers:           var lyr_THEBASEMAPOFKTIMATOLOGIO = new ol.layer.Tile({
                        source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                          url: "http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx?",
                          params: {"LAYERS": "KTBASEMAP", "TILED": "true"},
                        })),
                        title: "THE BASEMAP OF KTIMATOLOGIO"

Comment: QGIS can reproject the WMS internally from 4326 to 3857, but openlayers can not.

Comment: The missing quotation marks bug was fixed in qgis-ol3 (https://github.com/volaya/qgis-ol3/commit/0385ad64c964550899e6ad27616394cc19d74fe5).